# Google Sign in Problem with Android Studio in Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, google-signin

I'm using **Android Studio 3.2** on **Ubuntu 18.04**.
I always run Android Studio with **sudo**. Now I want to sign in to android studio to use **FireBase**. But it's stuck on "Please sign via the opened browser.." Dialog.

I followed all the instructions mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893931/unable-to-sign-in-to-google-account-in-android-studio/1083306?noredirect=1#comment1780918_1083306). Expect running Android Studio without root privileges. I want to sign in to android studio while running Android Studio with root privileges as I've many projects created with root privileges and don't want to change permission for all those.

Android Studio Window

[image: X]

Google Chrome Window

[image: X]

Answer (score 0):

Change to browser Firefox for sign in, its Ubuntu default browser. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change an owner for studio hidden folder and files inside. Look for .AndroidStudioX.X. Also i think you need to care about .android and .gradle folders.